# Java : Google Reverse Geocoding with jackson API

Tags: spring, google-maps, jackson

I want to get the address using the google Maps API. In my project we are using Jackson parser.

I want to know that, how can i get my expected result i.e. :-

```
"A10, Dhamidhar Rd, Yashkamal Society, Vasna, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380007, India"
```

I want to ignore all other fields in the API. As there are too many objects in the json file.
only want to fetch :

```
" "formatted_address" : "A10, Dhamidhar Rd, Yashkamal Society, Vasna, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380007, India","
```

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.0043673,72.5411868999996&sensor=false

Thank you

This is what I have tried

```
package com.example.api.batch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONPObject;

public class GeocodeAddressParser {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getLocationInfo( String lat, String lng) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=false");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode array =  mapper.readValue(stringBuilder.toString(), JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode object = array.get(0);
        String reportKey = object.get("results").textValue();
//      logger.info("ExportController : generatesExportExcel : parameters: {}", reportKey);
//      System.out.println("Map Keys:\n"+rawData.getStatus());
//      
//      List<GeocodeGetResult> locations = rawData.getResults();
//      
//      
//      for(int i=0; i < locations.size(); i++){
//          GeocodeGetResult object = locations.get(i);
//          System.out.println(object);
//      }


//      for(int i=0; i < locations.size(); i++){
//          SourceLocation object = locations.get(i);
//          //System.out.println(object.getClass().getName()+" "+object);
//          SourceLocation converted = convertSourceLocation(object);
//          System.out.println(converted);
//          toBeInserted.add(converted);
//      }
      //  JSONPObject jsonObject = new JSONPObject();
//      try {
//      //  ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
//          JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(stringBuilder.toString());
//         // jsonObject = new JSONObject();
//      } catch (JsonParseException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      return mapper;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{
        GeocodeAddressParser ref = new GeocodeAddressParser();

        ref.getLocationInfo("23.0043673","72.5411868999996"); 
//      ObjectMapper location;
//      String location_string;
//      try {
//          //Get JSON Array called "results" and then get the 0th complete object as JSON        
//          location = ret.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0); 
//          // Get the value of the attribute whose name is "formatted_string"
//          location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
//          Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);
//      } catch (JSONException e1) {
//          e1.printStackTrace();
//
//      }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have edited my question, check it

Comment: Check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getLocationInfo` method and replace the following part.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode array =  mapper.readValue(stringBuilder.toString(), JsonNode.class);
JsonNode object = array.get("results").get(0);
String reportKey = object.get("formatted_address").textValue();

System.out.println(reportKey);
```

In your given code,

```
JsonNode object = array.get(0);
```

This will return `null`(`object` contains `null`), because the result from the api link will return a object not an array. So, there is no `0` element here.